# Why is my delete action on the controller not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am new to rails.The delete action does not seem to find my @events and says NoMethodError. Am i missing something here? The create parts works like a charm but the delete link_to always throws an error.
 My events Controller and its action:-
     ```

```
      before_action :find_occasion
      before_action :find_event, only: [:destroy]
      def create
        @event = @occasion.events.create(params[:event].permit(:name, :location, :description, :isMakeAhead))
        redirect_to occasion_path(@occasion)
      end

      def destroy
          @event.destroy    <-- This line shows error while clicking on the link
          redirect_ to occasion_path(@occasion)
      end
      private

      def find_occasion        Got occasion id from here
        @occasion = Occasion.find(params[:occasion_id])
      end

      def find_event          Got event id from here
        @event= @occasion.events.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
```

````
And my views:-

    ```
        <%= event.name %>
        <%= event.location %>
        <%= event.description %>
        <p> <%= link_to "Delete Event", [event.occasion, event], method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></p>

    # I have tried the button_to too but it doesn't work.
````

This is what shows up when i use BETTER ERRORS GEM FILE.

```
    Request parameters  
    {"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"something", "controller"=>"events", "action"=>"destroy", "occasion_id"=>"2", "id"=>"14"}
    Rack session    
    (Object too large. Modify ActionDispatch::Request::Session#inspect or adjust BetterErrors.maximum_variable_inspect_size if you need to see it.)
    Local Variables
    Instance Variables
    @_action_has_layout 
    true
    @_routes    
    nil                  #routes shows nil i don't know why is that  
    @_action_name   
    "destroy"
    @_response_body 
    nil
    @marked_for_same_origin_verification    
    false
    @_config    
    {}
    @_params    
    <ActionController::Parameters {"_method"=>"delete",  "authenticity_token"=>"something", "controller"=>"events", "action"=>"destroy", "occasion_id"=>"2", "id"=>"14"} permitted: false>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `@comment` in the `find_event` method, but then using the variable `@event` in the `destroy` method. `@event` is not set up anywhere though. It might work if you use either

```
@comment.destroy
```

Or just change your `find_event` method to

```
def find_event       
  @event = @occasion.events.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Yea sorry that was my typo i forgot to change that. It still produces the same error.

Comment: I have updated the error page with a gem to be more clear. @Rockwell

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in my model which fixed my issue.